# Pattern Prototype(Не видит метод)

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, prototype

Не виден метод `setName`. Что делать, не пойму, все паблик.
С паттерном познакомился недавно, поэтому заранее извините.

```java
public class Salmon extends Fish implements Cloneable{

    public Salmon(){
        //...
    }
    private String name;

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return 220;
    }

    @Override
    public int getShelfLife() {
        return 16;
    }


    public Salmon copy(){
        Salmon salmon = new Salmon();
        return salmon;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

```java
public class Magazine {


    Box[] boxes = new Box[100];
    private int money;
    private int count;//Количество ящиков
    private int n; // Количество продаваемой рыбы
    private int x; // Количество прибывшей рыбы

    Salmon prototype = new Salmon();
    Salmon clone = prototype.copy();
        clone.setName(Salmon.String."Ribka#1"); // ЭТА СТРОКА, А ИМЕННО setName горит красным и ругается CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL SETNAME
}}
```

Comment: Вы вызываете метод у объекта просто внутри класса. А нужно внутри какого-то метода, ну, либо внутри блока инициализации...

Comment: Бл#!ь. Как же все просто! Спасибо))

Comment: `Salmon.String."Ribka#1"` - что это за запись?

Comment: Проинициализировал поле String name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл этот кусок кода поместить в метод.

```java
Salmon prototype = new Salmon();
    Salmon clone = prototype.copy();
        clone.setName(Salmon.String."Ribka#1");
```